# Is it legal to cover VIN? and/or useful?

Tags: vin, theft-prevention

A recommendation I heard recently to avoid some types of car theft is to cover your vehicle's VIN plate so potential thieves don't have ready access to the VIN.  I would like to know:

- Is it legal (in the USA) to cover your VIN plate?
- Is it even useful to cover your VIN plate?  Are the types of thefts enabled by having visual access to your car's VIN plate common enough that I should be worried about it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question and not about vehicle repair. It is also very broad with no single answer as it's dependent on federal, state and local laws which will vary.

Comment: VIN contains basic information that people knowing the model can tell from basic look. It usually contain the Make,Model, Year, Color and some option group selected. I don't see what use a theft would make out of it.

Comment: @Franck I suspect the thieves can somehow use the VIN to get hold of new keys (perhaps via an insider within a dealer?). More common is simply breaking into the house and stealing the keys however...

Comment: At least in NY, the VIN is on the registration sticker as well.  I can't imagine that it would be legal to cover that.

Comment: The VIN is sort of like PII for a vehicle, if you think about it. I've never heard of it being a requirement for it to be visible. If my vehicle were susceptible to being repo'd, I'd cover it up. A repo company is supposed to verify the VIN prior to towing the vehicle ... I guess if they are repo'ing it, though, they would most likely have a set of keys for it and could open the door to uncover it ;-) Yah, no clue on the legality of it, but don't know why it would be.

Comment: @NickC even if they cut a key that worked in the ignition and door cylinder it would still need to be programmed to the immobilizer. Which is non-trivial nowadays.

Answer (score -1):

I live in Virginia, northern VA to be precise. The cops are sort of sticklers up here, compared to more rural parts of VA.

For quite some time, I've been keeping an assortment of papers/maps wedged against the windshield on my dashboard. They just happen to cover the VIN. I have never had a problem with the police, so I am *assuming* that is not illegal to cover your VIN.

Comment: Why the down vote? <chin scratching emoji>